# List suggested friends

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join

I'm trying to get a list of suggested friends that are not within my friends but are in my friends, friends.

status of 2 being an accepted friend.

My session id is 34 and I'm friends with user 3 and user 3 is friends with user 16, so user 16 would show as a suggested friend as user 16 is not my friend.

***Friends table***

```
id | user 1_id | user2_id | status
----------------------------------
4       3          34        2
3       34         3         2
2       3          16        2
1       16         3         2
```

***Query*** (What I've tried)

```
$user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
$user2_id=$data['id'];
$collectmutualfriendsa = mysqli_query($mysqli,"
SELECT DISTINCT r2.user1_id
FROM
friends r
INNER JOIN friends r2
ON r.user1_id = r2.user2_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN friends r3 ON r3.user2_id = r2.user1_id AND r3.user1_id=2
WHERE r.user2_id = 2 AND r3.user1_id is null");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I tried a UNION and now have it working.

```
$collectmutualfriendsa = mysqli_query($mysqli,"
SELECT *
FROM friends
WHERE user2_id NOT IN
(
   SELECT user1_id FROM friends WHERE user2_id = '$user1_id'
   UNION 
   SELECT user2_id FROM friends WHERE user2_id = '$user1_id'
)

");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user1_id = $_SESSION['id']; // 34
$user2_id = $data['id']; // 3
$query = "SELECT * FROM Friends_table WHERE user1_id = '$user2_id' AND user2_id != $user1_id;";
```

Comment: Hi @vishnu. this query doesn't seem to be giving me the right result. It is printing out user 3 which is in my friends list. I would like to get only the friends of my friends list printed out. So any friends of user 3.

Comment: check possible if you are not printing user1_id instead of user2_id